# Est-ce que je dois utiliser l'infinitif passé après « à » ou non?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, infinitif

Dans phrase ci-dessous, je dois utiliser l'infinitif passé ou non ?

> Je vous remercie d’avoir consacré votre temps à me répondre.
>
> Je vous remercie d’avoir consacré votre temps à m'avoir répondu.

Comment: Très personnellement, votre seconde phrase me paraît bizarre. La première est mieux, néanmoins, je pense que "Je vous remercie d'avoir pris le temps de me répondre" est une phrase plus naturelle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les actions « consacrer votre temps » et « me répondre » se sont déroulées en même temps. La concordance des temps demande donc que « me répondre » soit au présent.

> Je vous remercie d’avoir consacré votre temps à me répondre.

« Consacré votre temps » est tout à fait compréhensible mais n'est pas correct. Cela signifie « consacré *tout* votre temps », sans insister sur le *tout*. Il faut utiliser un article partitif :

> Je vous remercie d’avoir consacré de votre temps à me répondre.

ou

> Je vous remercie d’avoir consacré du temps à me répondre.

Je trouve plus idiomatique de tourner la phrase autrement :

> Je vous remercie pour le temps que vous avez consacré à me répondre.

Answer (score 2):

La formulation habituelle est *à me répondre*. La seconde est presque syntactiquement incorrecte. Je ne suis pas sûr qu'elle le soit, mais je ne peux imaginer de contexte où *à* serait suivi de l'infinitif passé.

Toutefois, la formulation correcte est *du temps* et non *votre temps*:

> Je vous remercie d’avoir consacré du temps à me répondre.